# what type of Aws Ec2 instance can be used for Corda R3 nodes setup?

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, corda

I want to install Corda nodes on Aws Ec2 instance.
So Which instance type should I use for the Setup of Corda R3 nodes?
Can I use Single Ec2 Instance for configuring three Corda nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on your usage.

Do you plan to use AWS for Corda development? If so it might be good to look at the official R3 AWS image (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077PG9SP5).

In general, I suggest to assume that you need at least 512MB per node. However, this value might higher, depends on your CorDapps size. (BTW default starting value is 256MB. It is low and might cause problems, so I suggest to adjust it with the '-Xmx' Java flag). You will probably also want to run a webserver for node(s). Let's say it's requires 256MB per node. Finally, you need extra memory for OS (at least 1 GB to be save).

Based on above a VM with at least 4GB and 2 cores is a minimal starting point for your set up. However, with 3 nodes, I would go for at least 4 vCPUs and more memory. xlarge machines from the M family looks as a good choice.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It means that I can install 3 Corda nodes on the same EC2 instance or do I need a separate EC2 instance for separate node?  can you just help me out with this confusion?

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.